# Why does a child object move off of it's axis when keyframes are put in?

Tags: animation, keyframes, parent

[image]

I am trying to remake the Pixar Animation Studios logo in Blender 2.79. I tried using an armature to animate the lamp, but that was useless to me because of the abnormal deformities it caused, so I tried using parent-child animation instead. Now, when I try to move the lamp's head, the bottom of the lamp, or any other piece, it either moves or rotates much more, rotates back to where it was before, or even goes off of the place it's supposed to be in.

Can you please help me fix this with a solution that is helpful and easy?

Edit: I have finished it and saved it, but now I have used the technique of adding keyframes to Max rotation limits in Object Constraints, allowing me to animate the lamp like never before.

Comment: I think your best shot is still an armature, but you need to create the vertex groups for it yourself. I’ve made robot arms with blender armatures, and it works just fine. Trying to do child and parent relationships sounds extremely complicated.

Comment: Also, nice replica. Actually inspired me to do something similar. Though for legal safety, I recommend you change it to something else. 

Comment: I see from your timeline (screencap) that have at least some keyframes.  Select some of the other peices and see if you have first cleared all animation keyframes (any that you do not want), otherwise those sub-objects (lamp head) will snap back to where the existing (old, unwanted) animation keys tell it to be.

Comment: I assume @ZargulTheWizard "Though for safety" means for copyright and not for any lamp burns or electrical shocks? LOL

Comment: LOL, yes. Would make more jokes, but I’ll stick to the problem at hand. I’m really surprised that a parent child object relationship could be better than an armature. I really think you must’ve been using automatic weight setting or bone envelopes, when vertex groups is actually the best way to go in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the "replica," Zargul, but a user has to be making profits from one or more remakes of logos made in Blender to truly get sued by the company that owns the logotype, whether online or in real life.

Comment: @Ahmed Nasser Copyright law varies by country, locale, but in the USA, profit is not necessary to lose a suit.

Comment: https://youtu.be/M_y-zYCBk7w is a tutorial for exactly what you are trying